# Error de sintaxis al actualizar datos en java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tengo este código que, al momento de modificar datos, me tira el error de

```
you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
where paciente.id = 
at line 1
```

Me pueden apoyar indicándome el error ya que no encuentro la forma de como corregirlo

```
public void modificarpacientes( JTextField paraid, JTextField paraanimal, 
           JTextField paraedad, JTextField paranombre,
           JTextField paradiagnostico, JTextField paramedicamento ) {               

    setId(Integer.parseInt(paraid.getText()));
    setAnimal(paraanimal.getText());
    setEdad(Integer.parseInt(paraedad.getText()));
    setNombrepaciente(paranombre.getText());
    setDiagnosticopaciente(paradiagnostico.getText());
    setMedicamentopaciente(paramedicamento.getText());
      
    conexion.objetoconexion = new conexion();
           
    String consulta ="UPDATE pacient SET paciente.animal=?,paciente.edad=?, paciente.nombre=?,paciente.diagnostico=?,paciente.medicamento=?; where paciente.id=?";
           
    try {
         CallableStatement cs = objetoconexion
                        .establececonexion()
                        .prepareCall(consulta);
           
         cs.setInt(1, getId());
         cs.setString(2, getAnimal());
         cs.setInt(3, getEdad());
         cs.setString(4, getNombrepaciente());
         cs.setString(5, getDiagnosticopaciente());
         cs.setString(6, getMedicamentopaciente());                  
               
         cs.execute();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "se modifico exitosamente");                   
     } 
     catch (SQLException e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al modificar"+e.toString());
               
     }               
}
```

Comment: `UPDATE pacient SET paciente.`, `pacient` o `paciente`?? De todas maneras, como solo estás actualizando una única tabla puedes ignorar el nombre de la misma y simplemente poner los campos. Pero si usas el nombre de la tabla, debería ser el nombre de la tabla y no su traducción. Además... tienes un punto y coma antes del `where` que no tiene sentido ninguno.

Comment: El punto y coma **;** antes de la cláusula WHERE tiene toda la pinta de ser la causa del error de sintaxis.

Comment: te comparto el query corregido, la explicación ya  te apoyo Benito-B y alejandroMAD.

`UPDATE pacient 
SET animal=?, edad=?, nombre=?, diagnostico=?, medicamento=? 
WHERE id=?;`